# Isolating same data in Alteryx workflow

Tags: workflow, alteryx

I have a large set of data, however below shows only 4 entries. I want to isolate the rows that have the same entries. For instance, on table one you can see that the first two rows have the same value in the columns  number, ID, Brand, and Partner. I want to only get the rows with these same entries, so my final result will be Data Table 2.

[Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwNzn.png)

[Data Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3kCv.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is the quickest way I can think of
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ufbl6J-gwCi5OpqaGHmC93aHuA6g-gSi/view?usp=sharing

Actually, I've just realised the 'RecordID' is redundant so you can leave that tool out, I think?

[image]